# Angular getter is evaluated before constructore

Tags: angular, typescript

```
  constructor(
    private readonly authService: SocialAuthService,
    private readonly authS: AuthService,
    private readonly loginS: LoginService,
    private readonly router: Router,
    private readonly formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) {
    alert('c');
  }
  get foo() {
    alert('foo');
    return;
  }
```

alert('foo') appears before alert('c') I am not even using foo in my template how is this even possiable

https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipMx6TYGPyF6w3awHC5A5xJ8t0UmkYuqG42jHGxzsR95r-tBv1AyYAHxhirBBVgYgA?key=VVF5dnVTamFrMFk2dHluM29FZGJQdDk5eHpHeGJB

the video link is above I cant cpoy paste the hole code base

Comment: Please post a stackblitz of your attempt.

Comment: I can't post the whole code base on stackbliz. Can demo u that on a discord chat is ur free my user id is morfes#6592

Comment: And this is happening with all the components

Answer (score 0):

Can assure you, this doesn't happen. Here's a stackblitz for the same

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jbnmt8

If `foo` is being triggered, there must be a reason. Please share your Minimal reproducible code. People will be glad to help.